# Using Dependency Links for PyPi package

Tags: igraph, pypi

I need to link my pypi project to a specific page (to download python-igraph) which is here (https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). How would I modify my dependency_links array to link to the external download?

Answer (score 0):

The page uses javascript tricks to avoid being pointed to that way. It's a free resource, please don't overuse it by automatically download packages from it.